# how to take the value of an EditText when i press a button and print it on the screen

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-sharedpreferences

How to take the value of an EditText(e.g a birthday date) and when i press a button(Send) to print (Birthday date) on the screen [This is my Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94eTp.jpg)

Don t answer with hate commends i am learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use SharedPreferences you should use another button to save the text and another to retrieve it.

here is the code.

```
    Button saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
    Button restoreButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.restoreButton);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    final SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pref.edit().putString("autoSave", editText.getText().toString()).apply();
        }
    });

    restoreButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pref.getString("autoSave",null);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Okey you must first get a reference to the view by using findViewById()
the use the.
can you past your XML file.

Comment: i want to use SharedPreferences but i have 5 errors now 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/yfm2s.jpg 
Thank you 
i must read my theory lessons again from the beggining

Comment: I just edited my answer. I hope you find it clear.
if not please take a look again to the first lesson in your course because it's very basic stuff.

Comment: my teacher say that isn't correct :( i must find an other way to do it .

Comment: (In the exercise you must develop an application that will register and retrieve user records with the help of SharedPreferences. You must create 1 EditText in which you put the birthday and when we press the Send button this will print on the screen.)

I understand that I should write a date in the EditText and after I get the date from the EditText and display it in a TextView somewhere on the screen by pressing the button SEND but i dont know how to do it in one activity and with SharedPreferences

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = editText.getText().toString();
```

This is how you get your value.

Comment: Thank you and you know how to print it on the screen with Shared Preferences?

Answer (score 0):

First, take one EditText, one Button and one TextView. Then on button press event, take your EditText value and set it into TextView as the code is like below:

```
button_object.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
                textView_object.setText(editText_object.getText().toString());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

String text = editText.getText().toString();

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();